# Enter Australia on an expired passport

Tags: passports, australia

I am a dual Australian/British citizen. I have let my Australian passport expire, however due to a change in circumstances in the UK I am looking to return to Australia permanently within the next couple of weeks.

Will I be able to:

1. board a flight out of the UK on a one-way ticket?
2. be allowed to re-enter Australia with my expired passport

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the Australian High Commission [web site](https://uk.embassy.gov.au/lhlh/Pportfees.html) in London, you can renew your passport in three weeks (or just two days if you pay a priority fee). Doing so would avoid any issues with boarding flights or entering Australia.

Comment: According to the other question I've linked, it's possible you could be allowed to board, but it might depend on the gate staff being willing to phone the Australian Border Force. You could also try applying for an ETA for your British passport. Technically as an Australian you're not eligible, and it might be rejected as the other question states. But it would satisfy airline staff if you're successful. As Redd says, the best option is to renew if possible.